# How to detect email as reply whose subject line changed in gmail?

Tags: java, api, email, gmail

I have used gmail api in java to send and fetch email. I found it difficult to detect the reply of the sent email when the subject-line of reply email changed. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: You don't use the subject line to determine replies anyway, do you? There's an in-reply-to header you should use.

Comment: In case of changed subject-line, I got nothing to compare to detect the replies. If the user reply the email changing the subject-line then "In-Reply-To" header is not present.

Answer (score 0):

The only sure fire way to tell that an email is a reply is to either check for a subject beginning with `RE:`.

*(Side note, this is [good practice](http://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2011/06/dont-change-the-subject.html) for all professional correspondence, as changing the subject line makes it harder to catalog email chains).*

Aside from this method, as a back-up I supposed you could programmatically read the text in the body of the message. I know some email providers change the font color (and sometimes size) to add a slight blue/red/purple-ish hue to the body of an email if it is a reply.

Comment: When the subject-line changed, then the reply email comes in new thread; making it as a new email. No font size or color changed. It comes as a normal new email.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way of correlating the replies with the original emails is using the in-reply-to header.

However, when the subject line changes the in-reply-to header does not come back for most email providers like gmail, yahoo and even when using outlook client

We found that only outlook.com domain returns the in-reply-to header even if the subject line gets modified.

And all that is perfectly legal because following is what is mentioned on [RFC Page](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt)

> 3.6.5. Informational fields
>
> The informational fields are all optional.  The "Keywords:" field
>   contains a comma-separated list of one or more words or
>   quoted-strings. The "Subject:" and "Comments:" fields are
>   unstructured fields as defined in section 2.2.1, and therefore may
>   contain text or folding white space.
>
> subject         =       "Subject:" unstructured CRLF
>
> comments        =       "Comments:" unstructured CRLF
>
> keywords        =       "Keywords:" phrase *("," phrase) CRLF
>
> These three fields are intended to have only human-readable content
>   with information about the message.  The "Subject:" field is the most 
>   common and contains a short string identifying the topic of the
>   message.  When used in a reply, the field body MAY start with the
>   string "Re: " (from the Latin "res", in the matter of) followed by
>   the contents of the "Subject:" field body of the original message.
>   If this is done, only one instance of the literal string "Re: " ought 
>   to be used since use of other strings or more than one instance can
>   lead to undesirable consequences.  The "Comments:" field contains any 
>   additional comments on the text of the body of the message.  The
>   "Keywords:" field contains a comma-separated list of important words
>   and phrases that might be useful for the recipient.